[coc.nvim]: UnhandledRejection: spawn EINVAL
enter image description here
I am facing this error after I have installed coc-kotlin. I do not understand. I tried a lot but I could not resolve the problem.
I tried to setup the :CocConfig file to resolve the problem\
"languageserver": {
        "kotlin": {
            "command": "C:\\Users\\SHAHNUR\\AppData\\Local\\coc\\extensions\\coc-kotlin-data\\langServerInstall\\server\\bin\\kotlin-language-server.bat",
            "filetypes": ["kotlin"]
        }
    }

and there the bat file also showed an error when I tried to run it.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Content-Length: 127

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":3,"message":"main      Kotlin Language Server: Version 1.3.12"}}Content-Length: 108

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":3,"message":"main      Connected to client"}}

Nov 06, 2024 4:39:21 AM org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer fireError
SEVERE: Missing header Content-Length in input "

"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing header Content-Length in input "

"
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:113)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Content-Length: 140

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"client    Missing header Content-Length in input \"\r\n\r\n\""}}Content-Length: 163

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing header Content-Length in input \"\r\n\r\n\""}}Content-Length: 174

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"\tat org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.StreamMessageProducer.listen(StreamMessageProducer.java:91)"}}Content-Length: 182

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"\tat org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.json.ConcurrentMessageProcessor.run(ConcurrentMessageProcessor.java:113)"}}Content-Length: 165

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)"}}Content-Length: 150

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)"}}Content-Length: 173

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)"}}Content-Length: 173

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)"}}Content-Length: 132

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"window/logMessage","params":{"type":1,"message":"\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)"}}

this is what got after I run.

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78420489/error-when-running-npm-script-with-yarn-err-spawn-einval.
